# Amazon Connect & Salesforce: Lambda not working --- "errorMessage": "invalid_request: must use HTTP POST",

Tags: aws-lambda, salesforce, amazon-connect

I am trying to test AWS lambda function that i deployed to test the Salesforce integration by invoking event-phoneLookup but getting below error. With the help of the integration document i had created a lambda application.
"errorMessage": "invalid_request: must use HTTP POST",
"errorType": "Exception",

Can someone please help me what should i need to check.